# CDATA Issue. Line break texts next to image

Tags: xml, kml, cdata

I need to line up texts next to the image from top to bottom.

I use `<br/>` inside `CDATA`, but the texts are line up in the bottom of image. How do I fix the issue so the text can line up next to the image from top?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Placemark>
        <name>Miami, FL</name>
<description>       
        <![CDATA[<img      
src="http://wfarm1.dataknet.com/static/resources/icons/set95/5076c9d9.png"/>   
<br/>
         Address: 180 Howard St. San Francisco, CA 94105. <br />      
         Phone:415-555-3322. <br/>
         Type: Kids Play Center. <br/>
         Fax: 515-666-3311]]>
 </description>
     <Point><coordinates>-80.19179,25.76168</coordinates></Point>
</Placemark>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a bit of CSS here:

```
<img src="..." style="float:left;"/>
Address: ... <br />
Phone: ... <br/>
Type: ... <br/>
Fax: ...
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also use a table here. It's more old-school than CSS, but it works too:

```
<![CDATA[
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://wfarm1.dataknet.com/static/resources/icons/set95/5076c9d9.png"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      Address: 180 Howard St. San Francisco, CA 94105. <br />      
      Phone: 415-555-3322. <br/>
      Type: Kids Play Center. <br/>
      Fax: 515-666-3311
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
]]>
```

Comment: Happily, it has been about two decades since CSS was introduced so we don't need to resort to hacks like this any more. Tables are for tabular data, not layout.

Comment: Yes, this is very true on the web, but we're talking here about web views in Google Earth, which unfortunately are a somewhat different beast.  Until just this year (2017), most versions of Google Earth used a very old version of QT+WebKit for rendering HTML in balloons.  It had very limited CSS support, so tables were still a good, simple, backwards-compatible option, at least for basic balloons. Now that classic Earth (v7) supports QT5 and the new versions of Google Earth (v9) support the latest browsers, the benefit of tables over CSS is almost gone.